# How do you execute an AWS Cli script

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to execute this following script but I no idea how to execute a script on the AWS CLI.

```
FUNCTION_NAME=omwealth-single-needs-web-api-key
for region in $(aws --output text  ec2 describe-regions | cut -f 3) 
do
    for loggroup in $(aws --output text  logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name "/aws/lambda/us-east-1.$FUNCTION_NAME" --region $region --query 'logGroups[].logGroupName')
    do
        echo $region $loggroup
    done
done
```

Comment: Its a `bash` script. So on a linux instance or a localhost linux box?

Comment: If you talk about aws solution, then Cloud9 or Code Build should do the trick

Comment: @John Where do you wish to run this script? On your own computer, or on an Amazon EC2 instance? Which operating system are you using (Linux, Windows, Mac)?